# Python: Help fixing the reset function on my stopwatch

Tags: python, stopwatch

I am trying to make a stopwatch, counting up from 0, which can be restarted when it receives user input. However, when I try the reset function it doesn't reset the timer to 0, but simply continues counting. I'm using threading so that it will continue counting and wait for user input, so I'm not sure how to fix it:

```
import time                   
import signal          
import threading    


def interrupted(signum, frame):          
    pass

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, interrupted) 

def count(s):      
   
    while True:
            print(format(s))
            s = s+1
            time.sleep(1)
        

def i_input():    #this is the alert for interaction and the reset trigger when interacted with.
    try:
        print('Starting Stopwatch')
        interact = input()
        print('Stopwatch Reset.')
        s=0
        i_input()
        
    except:
        return
        

def count(s):     
    while True:
        print(s)
        s = s+1
        time.sleep(1)
  



threading.Thread(target = i_input).start()
countThread = threading.Thread(target=count, args=(0,));
countThread.start();
```

If anyone could tell me how to make it reset back to 0 upon user input it would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: Why is `count` defined twice?

Comment: Please reduce and enhance this into the expected [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.

Comment: The variable `s` is a local variable in `count`, so you can't just change it in `i_input`. An easy solution is just to make it a global variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s` in your code is a local variable in the `count` function, so you can't change it in `i_input`.

When you do `s=0` in `i_input`, that just defined another local variable also named `s`, but it's local to a different scope so it doesn't change `count`'s `s`.

The solution is to make `s` a global variable. You can do this by defining it at the top level, and then putting `global s` in the functions so it doesn't get shadowed by a local variable.

```py
import time
import threading


def count(): 
    global s    
    while True:
        print(s)
        s += 1
        time.sleep(1)
        

def i_input():  # this is the alert for interaction and the reset trigger when interacted with.
    global s
    print('Starting Stopwatch')
    interact = input()
    print('Stopwatch Reset.')
    s = 0
    i_input()


s = 0
threading.Thread(target=i_input).start()
threading.Thread(target=count).start()
```